# Creating an up/down vote button with a counter using html/css

Tags: html, css, button

I am fairly new to html/css and need to create something like the following:

```
-----------------
|   |        UP |
| # | foobar    |
|   |        DN |
-----------------
```

Where UP and DN are some images indicating and upvote and downvote. The # is the net result of the UP and DN votes. So I am fairly well versed in javascript to handle the ajax/server-side. My skills primarily lack in the html/css - the actual UI design of these kinds of buttons.

Does anyone have advice on CSS topics I should look into or some good tutorials on the web that can teach me how to make this step by step? Even a high level idea of how I should proceed to make this or break this into pieces would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the actual up and downvote arrows, either do some serious scaling with the ↑↓ characters or use images. (You could technically get really fancy with z-index and CSS3 rotating and make it with pure CSS, but let's not go there. :)

There's a few ways to get that basic layout you want. You'll need two blocks: a number block and a up/down block. Those blocks can be laid out with CSS's `display:inline-block`, where the elements behave like block level elements (which means you can set width/height, etc.) but display on the same line as each other. Keep in mind `inline-block` is not supported by IE7 and lower, though you can hack it with `display:inline; zoom:1` set just for IE7 lower.
Or you could float the two elements left/right. This often has some odd side effects though.

Some actual markup might look like:

```
<div class="votesBox">
    <div class="votes">5</div>
    <div class="vote">
        <div class="voteUp">UpVote</div>
        <div class="voteDown">DownVote</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.votes, .vote {
 display:inline-block;
}
.vote {
 vertical-align:middle;   
}
```

You could replace .voteUp and .voteDown with images and wire click events to JS, then update the .votes's content accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/WpxAm/1/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box_model

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this before @Thomas posted his answer, so I'll post it anyway. It also comes with a complimentary, free [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/QzK3g/).

In essence, use `display: inline-block` along with `vertical-align: middle` or `line-height: 30px` (or however many px) to position things.

Comment: Thanks :-) Looking at your JSFiddle, I'd recommend that over mine - it's cleaner and lighter, although mine works too.

Comment: Your fiddle is a little more polished, though. :)

Comment: I'll let other people be the judge of that :-P I'm a perfectionist, so everything has to be right! It's why I put the `</div>` and `<div>` on the same line to remove the spacing for `inline-block`.

Comment: @OP: Please note that you should add `display: *inline; zoom: 1` to your CSS to get the `inline-block` elements to display in IE7- properly. I _think_ IE8 and above support `inline-block` properly.

Comment: fyi, you can set the parent's font-size to 0 (make sure you set the child font-size back up to normal though) and it takes care of the default spacing around the inline-block elements. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QzK3g/5/)

Comment: @JamWaffles let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1161/discussion-between-thomas-shields-and-jamwaffles)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these topics:

1. CSS Positioning
2. CSS Floats
3. CSS box model

that's almost all you need for this :)